# Required class javax.faces.FactoryFinder does not exist in selected libraries

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2, java-ee-8

I'm trying to create managed bean in eclipse's dynamic web project. There I need to add support for `@ManagedBean` annotation. I tried this way..

Right Click on Project > Properties > Project Facet > Checked JavaServer Faces > Download Library > then the library is downloaded automatically `Trinidad 2.0 (Apache MyFaces Trinidad API 2.0.1)`

Then I click this library after that I saw this error on the top.
`Required class javax.faces.FactoryFinder does not exist in selected libraries.`

I tried to add the [javax.faces-2.3.0.jar](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.0/javax.faces-2.3.0.jar) in the library but still same error. Any other solution?

Comment: Have you tried  to add j2ee.jar from your appserver directory to Eclipse library?

Comment: No. where is j2ee.jar currently in?

Comment: Here you can find a screenshot: http://ibmquestions.blogspot.com/2013/10/eclipse-error-required-class.html

Comment: still same error.